Bump doesn't look the same in viewport and render
I am creating a vinyl record in Blender and used a wave texture to add bump in the shader editor. But the bump almost doesn't show in the final render.
Viewport:

Final Render:

Here is my .blend file:


hello could you please pack the images and share your file?

If you don't share your file, perhaps a screenshot of which renderer being used (Cycles?) and how many rendering samples and denoise settings....

You have a white background in your final render or is it transparent?

It is transparent @Emir

I added the .blend file :) @moonboots

Render settings
Your settings between viewport and render don't match. You have 2 settings to change to get the same result in both view :


Denoising : one is enabled, not the other one
Max Samples : if set too low, it will stop rendering before reaching your Noise Threshold of 0.01. Let it be 1024px for both to be sure.

Render resolution
Your resolution was set to 6000x4000 px. I'm guessing your screen is smaller than that : which means you have to zoom in to be a valid comparison. If your looking at your whole render with a HD display, Blender has no choice but to simplify 6000px to 1920px. Press Numpad 1 in render view to display the render at 1:1 scale.
Here is the comparison (after reducing 6000x4000px to HD) :


That's a good point, thank you! But even when I match these settings the problem isn't fixed. What else can cause that?

Hard to say without your blend file : https://blend-exchange.com/

I added it underneath my quesiton :)

@EyalCohen I've updated my answer.

It helped! Thank you :) @Lutzi
